# Error in a regex accepting special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, jsp

I'm using a regex to test the validity of a name. This is the code:

```
if (!/^[A-Za-zÀ-Ÿ- ]+$/.test(value)) {
  doSomething()
}
```

Unfortunately in the browser I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: **/^[A-Za-zÃ€-È•- ]+$/:** Range out of order in character class.

The minified js has the code correctly compiled, but I load this .js file in .jsp file on my server. How does this influence the final messed up expression that I ended up with?

Comment: The expression in the error you report isn't the same as the expression in the example code. Are you sure that's the exact expression you're using?

Comment: Yes. I suspect that the .jsp where I'm loading the js code has something to do with this.
I believe it doesn't support special characters and it's altering the regular expression.

Comment: Seems like an encoding error. Could be the `.jsp` file itself or could be the application server

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though the browser is interpreting the special characters in a character set other than `utf-8`. Make sure the web page is set to use `utf-8` encoding.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Another idea to help with the regular expressions is to use [unicode escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#regular_expression_and_unicode_characters). This may help with the encoding issue regardless of encoding.

You could replace the regex as such (assuming I have the character codes correct):

```js
if (!/^[A-Za-z\u{c380}-\u{c5b8}- ]+$/.test(value)) {
  doSomething();
}
```

And if you wanted to check for `-` in your expression, probably escape it as well (`\-`).

```js
if (!/^[A-Za-z\u{c380}-\u{c5b8}\- ]+$/.test(value)) {
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I added a new line in the jsp and this fixed the issue for me.
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>